# plss help to write a program for solving a queue problem

Tags: python, arrays, stack, queue

I need to solve the following task but have no idea how to solve it.
You are given an array of `0` and `1`. `0` means that a new user has entered the store. `1` means that the visitor has been served. How many people should have been in the queue initially (**the minimum number**) for the script to be implemented (*you can't serve a visitor if the queue is empty*).

Sample Input:

```
0 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) to see what you should do to get help here with your homework. At least show what you have tried and that you made an effort in solving this problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 1 to a counter for each 0, and subtract 1 for each 1.
Your answer will simply be the smallest negative number counter takes:

```py
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
counter = 0
minm = 0
for x in arr:
   if x:
      counter -= 1
   else:
      counter += 1
   minm = min(minm, counter)
print(-1*minm)
```